# Simple interactive stock candlestick chart

Tags: javascript, candlestick-chart

Does anyone know how to make a simple candlestick chart in javascript, the chart needs to have volume, price, and needs to be interactive.  Any code or links would help greatly, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's some example code here: [TechanJS Candlestick](http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/27c4a333b0e0813e093d)

Comment: in the link that you provided me, do i have to manually input the data every time?

Comment: In that example, the data is being read from a CSV file. So if you wanted the data to be dynamic, you'll have to find a way to dynamically generate the CSV file.

Comment: what if i wanted to have it in real time, could i hook it up to lets say a yahoo finance, or google finance?

Comment: You could write code to poll whatever source you want, such as yahoo or google, make sure the data is formatted correctly, then save the results to the CSV file on a fixed time interval, every minute for example. Then regenerate the chart obviously once the data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities but I recommend the D3js library (d3js.org). It has a lot of grapical possibilities including interaction.

For a code example you have to be more specific and explain what you have tried so far.